# Creating Audit log for batch processing in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading some csv files from a folder using

```
spark.read.format("csv").load("<path>")
```

I want to create a table which contains the files which are processed by the above command , job status and number of records in the files

Please suggest me any way how can I achieve that.